# Using the method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

How do you solve
$$
\begin{cases}u_t-\frac{x}{t^2+1}u_x=0, & x,t\in\mathbb{R}\\u(0,x)=u_0(x)\in C^1(\mathbb{R})\end{cases}
$$
by the method of characteristics?

My approach is to consider the parametrisation  $t=t(\tau,\xi), x=x(\tau,\xi), u=u(\tau,\xi)$. Then the ODE to solve are
$$
\begin{align*}
&\frac{dt}{d\tau}=1\\
&\frac{dx}{d\tau}=-\frac{x}{t^2+1}\\
&\frac{du}{d\tau}=0
\end{align*}
$$
with initial conditions
$$
\begin{align*}
&t(0,\xi)=0\\
&x(0,\xi)=\xi\\
&u(0,\xi)=u_0(\xi).
\end{align*}
$$
Solving this, what I get is
$$
t=\tau,\quad u=u_0(\xi),\quad x=-\frac{x}{t^2+1}t+\xi.
$$

(Does this make sense? I have the feeling that it should be $x(t,\xi)=-\frac{\xi}{t^2+1}t+\xi$ instead.)

I have two questions:

(A) Isn't the right-hand side of
$$
\frac{dx}{d\tau}=-\frac{x}{t^2+1}
$$
globally Lipschitz continuous with respect to the second argument $x$, since
$$
\left\lvert\frac{-x_1+x_2}{t^2+1}\right\rvert\leqslant \lvert x_2-x_1\rvert?
$$
Doesn't this imply that this ODE has a unique global solution defined for all $(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ which then implies that the given PDE above has a unique global solution?

(2) How can I get an explicit expression of $u(x,t)$ depending on $u_0$?

Answer (score 1):

$$u_t-\frac{x}{t^2+1}u_x=0$$
The Charpit-Lagrange system of ODEs is :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{-\frac{x}{t^2+1}}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{du}{0} \quad\implies\quad du=0$
$$u=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{-\frac{x}{t^2+1}}$ which is separable. Solving it leads to :
$$xe^{\tan^{-1}(t)}=c_2$$
The general solution expressed on the form of implicit equation $c_1=F(c_2)$ is :
$$u(x,t)=F(xe^{\tan^{-1}(t)})$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to the condition :
$$u(x,0)=u_0(x)=F(xe^{\tan^{-1}(0)})=F(x)$$
Now the function $F(X)$ is determined whatever the variable $X$ is :
$$F(X)=u_0(X)$$
We put this function into the above general solution where $X=xe^{\tan^{-1}(t)}$.

The particular solution satisfying the specified condition is :
$$u(x,t)=u_0(xe^{\tan^{-1}(t)})$$

OTHER METHOD :

Change of variables :
$$\theta=\tan^{-1}(t)$$
$$\xi=\ln|x|$$
The PDE is transformed into :
$$u_\theta-u_\xi=0$$
I suppose that you know how to solve it with the method of characteristic or other method. The general solution is 
$$u(\xi,\theta)=f(\xi+\theta)$$
$f(\chi)$ is an arbitrary function, with $\chi=\xi+\theta$ .

Let $f(\chi)=F(e^\chi)$ where $F$ is an arbitrary function since $f$ is arbitrary.
$$u(\xi,\theta)=F(e^{\xi+\theta})$$
$e^{\xi+\theta}=xe^{\tan^{-1}(t)}$
$$u(x,t)=F(xe^{\tan^{-1}(t)})$$

Comment: I get that $u=xe^{\tan^{-1}(t)}e^{-\tan^{-1}(0)}$. I do not see how I now get $u_0$ into this.

Comment: This is shown in the first part of my answer. The particular solution satisfying the specified condition is :
$$u(x,t)=u_0(xe^{\tan^{-1}(t)})$$